# Search by name instead of id

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api2

I'm learning the Asp.net web api 2.0 and the current CRUD method just searches by id so I attempted to make it search by a title of a book but I've been unsuccessful.

What I added to the `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{name}",
    defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional }
};
```

And the part I'm having trouble with:

```
// GET: api/Books/Name
[ResponseType(typeof(Book))]
public IHttpActionResult GetBook(string name)
{
    Book book = from a in db.Books where a.Title == name select a;

    if (book == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        return Ok(book);
    }
}
```

However it would let me build this, on the line where I'm trying to run the LINQ query I get an error of: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<BookService.Models.Book>'to 'BookService.Models.Book'.`

I tried changing the query around to be `Book book = db.Books.Where(a => a.Title == name).AsQueryable();` but I still get the same error.

Comment: `Book book = db.Books.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Title == name);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns a result set of [IQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.100).aspx). Change

```
Book book = from a in db.Books where a.Title == name select a;
```

to

```
var books  = from a in db.Books where a.Title == name select a;
```

and then you need to iterate on the result set.

Or if you only need the first result set then you can use [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Book book = db.Books.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Title == name);
```

Comment: It appears now I get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<BookService.Models.Book>'to'System.Collections.Generic.IList<BookService.Models.Book>'`

Comment: Well that worked, but now when I navigate to it and type a title such as `/api/books/Pride` It just brings up a blank page. Do you happen to see any other errors with my code?

Comment: Ah completely my fault, was searching for Pride and Prejudice so I had to put `(a => a.Title.Contains(name));`